# how to fix "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'form.submit.addEventListener')"

Tags: javascript, ajax, undefined

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get a basic AJAX form to work and am particularly stumped with the current issue. 
I have a bit of code which always errors. Here is the error message:

`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'form.submit.addEventListener')`

... and here is the bit of code that causes the error:

```
form.submit.addEventListener('click', () => {

  console.log('button pressed!');

});
```

I honestly have no idea why, as I'm using the arrow function so it shouldn't be undefined should it? I'm pretty new to javascript so I've probably missed something I'm just very confused as of now.

Comment: what is `form`? if it's defined, does it have a `submit` property? If it does, does this `submit` property have an `addEventListener` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *AJAXify* your form, listen to the form `submit` Event, not to button clicks.

```
const form = document.querySelector("#formidable");

form.addEventListener("submit", async (ev) => {

  ev.preventDefault(); // prevent browser triggering action
  console.log('Someone tried to submit my formidable form!');

  // Than do your Ajax Magic!
  const response = await fetch(form.action, {
    method: form.method || "post",
    body: new FormData(form)
  });

  const result = await response.json();
  console.log(result.message); // log the response JSON from server!

});
```

If not deferred, make sure your `<script>` tag is placed right before the closing `</body>` tag in order to make sure DOM is parsed and ready.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply!
I've just tried all of this but I seem to be getting essentially the same error (`null is not an object (evaluating 'form.submit.addEventListener')`) as before it was the same but undefined rather than null...
Not sure where to go from here, any ideas?

Comment: @jec1918 you're welcome. Can you please point me to where exactly you see `form.submit.addEventListener` in my answer? The "submit" Event listener should be attached to the form itself. See the querySelector?

Comment: sorry that was just a typo on my part! It actually is just `form.addEventListener`, and I'm still getting the same error. Also I am unable to put the `<script>` tag just before the `</body>` tag as I am using php includes inside a few `<div>` tags (for consistent page layout). so the `<script>` tag still has footer.php and the bootstrap CDN `<script>` link below it on the page - will this effect the DOM?

Comment: @jec1918 if a `console.log(form)` (added to the second line) gives you in console `undefined` that obviously means that JS did not found any form in the DOM at that point in time. One way is to `defer` your script loading; or use document ready; or simply place your scripts where it's best. And that's right before the closing `</body>` tag, instead of breaking (pausing) HTML parsing due to the loading of the JavaSript interpreter.